# "A is not defined" inside of <aui:script> block

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, alloy-ui

I'm trying to extend some functionality of an existing Liferay portlet.  As part of this, I would like to use Alloy UI to modify the value of a field in the portlet.  There's a pre-existing `<aui:script>` block where I would like to define my custom function.  I went ahead and tried using `A.one('element')`, but I am receiving the error "A is not defined."  `A.one()` is used elsewhere in the same .jsp file, though not in an `<aui:script>` block, and it functions as expected.

I have tried Googling this problem to no avail.  One solution that I tried was to include the "use" statement in the element block, but this made all of the functions in that block undefined when called from the jsp.

What I mean by the "use" statement is this:

```
<aui:script use="aui-node,aui-base">
    // ... script
</aui:script>
```

Here's a rough outline of what I'm trying to do:

```
<aui:script>
    function save(){
        // This is where I'm getting the 'A is not defined' error.
        var titleNode = A.one('input[name=title]');

        if (titleNode) {
            // do stuff with titleNode
            var titleVal = titleNode.val();
            var titleSubstr = titleVal.substring(0, titleSubstr.lastIndexOf('/'));
            titleNode.val(titleSubstr);
        }

        // other save-related code here
    }

    function otherFunction() {
        // some other functionality
    }
</aui:script>
```

Comment: i don't know much about "AUI" but still you can "document.getElementsByName("title")[0].value" to get element value

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`<aui:script>` tag outputs

```
AUI().use(function(A) {
}
```

only if you provide dependencies via `use` attribute. Like

```
<aui:script use="aui-base">
    // your code here
</aui:script>
```

If you do so, you'll have

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    AUI().use('aui-base', function(A) {
        // your code here
    }
</script>
```

as a result. But in this case, all functions you declare inside  will not be global. To make them global call

```
Liferay.provide(window, 'functionName', function() {
    // function body
});
```

inside `<aui:script/>`

Also `<aui:script use="aui-base"/>` is better than manually calling `AUI().use(function(A) {})` if client can have IE <= 7, that doesn't work correctly with `AUI().use()`. In case of IE 6,7 `<aui:script use="aui-base>` will output `AUI().ready('aui-base', function(A) {});` which will work in old browsers.

Comment: Great and detailed answer!

Comment: I haven't tested this yet, but this sounds like it will exactly fix my issue.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: -" Also <aui:script use="aui-base"/> is better than manually calling AUI().use(function(A) {}) "
then jsp is better than javascript.
that made me mad! ... both approaches MUST be equivalent

Answer (score 0):

The [blog post here](http://www.liferay.com/web/nathan.cavanaugh/blog/-/blogs/alloyui-working-with-elements-and-events) gives a good introduction to AUI. In particular, the following excerpt from the beginning of the post answers your direct question:

```
How do you create a sandbox?

Simple:

AUI().use(function(A) {
   // Your code goes here  
});
```

Comment: I assumed that the <aui:script> tag set the sandbox up for me.  Also, "A" is referenced elsewhere in the same file without explicitly calling `AUI().use`... and it works as expected.