# LifeRay form validation using Alloy UI

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, alloy-ui

I use LifeRay 6.1.2. And it have built-in Alloy UI 1.5. framework. So I try to reproduce [this](http://alloyui.com/versions/1.5.x/examples/form-validator/) form validation example (I copied all code), but it don't work as expected (error labels in DOM, but they are don't visible in form (see EDIT1)):

[image]

Expected result is (you can try yourself live example using link provided above):

[image]

Where is problem? How to solve it? Thanks.

**EDIT1:**
After some research, I realized that if I delete `aui-form-validator-message` CSS class from error message's DIV tag (it generated by LifeRay, I'm not adding it), then error message become visible. Strange..

Comment: Can you tell me how can I design this same form as my format ..?? One Row.. Left Side Text, Right side related control using alloy ui tag?

Answer (score 4):

You should post your own code, or it's difficult to answer.
Anyway if you want you could try the aui validator tag for example:

```
<aui:input name="name" value="${name}" label="name">
     <aui:validator name="required" errorMessage="your-message-here"></aui:validator>
</aui:input>
```

learn more @ http://drewblessing.com/blog/-/blogs/34509

Hope it helps!

Comment: remember to put it in an aui:form. this works for input text. With input select (dropdown lists) thats a different story.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not used the tag in your code.

```
<script src="http://cdn.alloyui.com/2.0.0/aui/aui-min.js"></script>
```

Paste this and check.